# Zip file unable to expand after being posted to S3 from SFTP server using node and AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, fs

After reading zipped files from an sftp server and posting them to S3, the files are not able to be downloaded and read.  The error from the console when trying to unzip the files reads as follows:

```
unzip -l 7375_FAIL_test_20160626_185904.txt.zip 
Archive:  7375_FAIL_test_20160626_185904.txt.zip
warning [7375_FAIL_test_20160626_185904.txt.zip]:  4 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [7375_FAIL_test_20160626_185904.txt.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

The js code for reading the the file from sftp is here:

```
.then(function(fileInfo) {
return sftp.openAsync(dir + '/' + fileInfo.filename, 'r')
.then(function(handle) {
  console.log(fileInfo.attrs.size)
  var result = new Buffer(fileInfo.attrs.size);
  return sftp.readAsync(handle, result, 0, fileInfo.attrs.size, 0)
  .then(function(data) {
    return process(result.toString());
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    return sftp.closeAsync(handle)
    .then(function() {
      return data;
    });
  })
```

Any thoughts on why `4 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile` might be happening or how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I wanna do almost same thing.. Can you please share the lambda code with me? I might debug and help you after that.

Comment: Is `process()` where you upload the code to S3? If so, you probably shouldn't be calling `.toString()` on `result`.

Comment: @AkarshSatija unfortunately the repo is private, but it's really just a customized version of https://github.com/gilt/s3-sftp-bridge

Comment: @robertklep there's now a weird issue where large files being set to s3 with putObject are being trimmed somehow, so a file that's 650kb ends up in s3 as 638kb.  Then, some files are corrupt and some aren't.  I tested and the file size being passed in body for s3.putObject is the correct size, so the truncation is definitely happening in the AWS SDK process. Any ideas?

Comment: @weilandia I guess it would depend on how exactly that file is transferred to S3, difficult to say without code what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://www.cloudzipinc.com/ that expands several different formats of archives from S3 into a destination prefix in your bucket, and it can copy FTP sites to S3.  I used it to move a digital catalog from FTP to S3.